# Password authentication failed

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I'm doing an express API and i was testing my connection with database on a post route, but i got this error.  the error says that password failed, but i feel like i filled the env file correctly, and after that i reviewed and nothing seems wrong. Obs. i guess is not a conflict between postgres user and system user, because i have a user with the same name in postgres and my operational system as well.

```
function validUser(user){
  const validEmail = typeof user.email === 'string' && user.email.trim() !== '';
  const validPassword = typeof user.password === 'string' && user.password.trim() !== ''
  user.password.trim().length >=6;
  
  return validEmail && validPassword;
}
```

```
  const {email, password} = req.body;
  const user = {
    email,
    password
  }
  if(validUser(user)){
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10);

    pool.query(
      `SELECT * FROM usuarios where email = $1`, [user.email], (err, results) => {
        if(err){
          throw err;
        }
        console.log(results.rows);
      }
    )
  }else{
    res.json({message:"Invalid informations"})
  }
})
```

Comment: Your `else` statement is dependent on the result of `if(validUser)`, where you probably want it inside the `pool.query` due to the callback and async nature of the query.

Comment: i didnt understand whats your point. Do you think the else statement is related to failed authentication?

Comment: None of the code you show us is relevant to the API server connecting to the database.  Your code seems to be about the end user connecting to the API server, which is an entirely different thing.